# Cannot resolve bios dependency for soundscope-player

Tags: python, arch-linux

I am trying to install soundscope-player on Arch Linux. After much fumbling around I have finally gotten down to 1 missing dependency. I looked through the python install and config script and it looks like it is looking for a bios file in /usr/share/psx/ but I have tried moving the bios file here and it still didnt work. I have duckstation installed and am able to boot into the bios normally. Duckstation was installed through AUR.
Is there another location I should be moving the psx bios file?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/psx-bios

Comment: I don't know how you installed it but you can see the dep list with links on https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/soundscope-player

Comment: Specific and complete error codes? What BIOS file?